# SSL certificate - are wildcards in SAN extension allowed or not?

Tags: ssl, x509certificate, weblogic11g, rfc

I hit a compatibility issues with Oracle Weblogic and an SSL certificate which uses wildcard DNS names in in the Subject Alternate Names (SAN) extension. Seems that none of the modern browsers have a problem with that, but according to Thawte and Oracle for example this is not allowed and Weblogic's wildcard hostname verifier miserably fails - apparently by design:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/apirefs.1111/e13941/weblogic/security/utils/SSLWLSWildcardHostnameVerifier.html

"DNSNames obtained from the peer certificate's SubjectAlternativeNames extension may not be wildcarded"

Other CAs seem to be perfectly alright with issuing such certs.

RFC 5280 seems to leave implementation in this case up in the air:

"Finally, the semantics of subject alternative names that include wildcard characters (e.g., as a placeholder for a set of names) are not addressed by this specification.  Applications with specific   requirements MAY use such names, but they must define the semantics."

With the obvious security considerations aside are there any rules which apply?

PS
Now I can really appreciate having standards...

Comment: this is obviously very old but having same problem, did you get this going?

Comment: Sorry, no. It was a long time ago. At the end we probably asked the other party to get another certificate. I don't think Weblogic's behaviour changed...

Comment: thanks for the response. the behaviour is indeed the same. disabling the hostname verification works but is not desirable.

Answer (score 1):

SAN with wildcards are perfectly valid for HTTPS. RFC5280 ist probably not the right RFC for this stuff since it leaves these details out. Better look at RFC6125 and RFC2818.
But of course wildcards have restrictions. You can only use them in the leftmost label (no `*.*.com`) and they only match a single label, that is `*.example.com` matches `www.example.com` but not `www.foo.example.com`.